# $cf(\aleph_{\alpha}) \geq cf(\alpha)$ for all limit ordinals $\alpha$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I am trying to prove the following Lemma:

> Lemma: Let $\alpha$ be a limit ordinal. Then $cf(\aleph_{\alpha}) = cf(\alpha)$.

I am using the following definitions:

> Definition: Let $(\mathbb{P}, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set. A subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{P}$ is said to be cofinal if for all $p \in \mathbb{P}$ there exists $q \in A$ such that $p \preceq q$.

> Definition: Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal. The cofinality of $\alpha$ is the least ordinal $\lambda$ such that there exists a function $f: \lambda \to \alpha$ whose range is cofinal in $(\alpha, \leq)$. We denote the cofinality of $\alpha$ by $cf(\alpha)$.

There is also a useful lemma:

> Lemma: Let $\alpha$ be a non-zero ordinal number. Then there exists a strictly increasing function $f: cf(\alpha) \to \alpha$ whose range is cofinal in $(\alpha,\leq)$.

My idea is to prove the lemma in question is to prove that $cf(\aleph_{\alpha}) \leq cf(\alpha)$ and $cf(\alpha) \leq cf(\aleph_{\alpha})$. I have already proven that $cf(\aleph_{\alpha}) \leq cf(\alpha)$. My idea for the other direction is as follows:

Proof idea: By definition there exists a function $f:cf(\aleph_{\alpha}) \to \aleph_{\alpha}$ such that $ran(f)$ is cofinal in $(\aleph_{\alpha},\leq)$. Let $x \in \alpha$, then there is $\theta \in cf(\aleph_{\alpha})$ such that $f(\theta) \geq x$. So, {$f(\beta): \beta \in cf(\aleph_{\alpha}), f(\theta) \geq x$} is non-empty, and thus has a least element $\gamma$.

Now if I can prove that $\gamma \in \alpha$, then I could define the function

$h=${$(x,y) \in f: f(x) \in \alpha$} $\cup$ {$(x,y) \in dom(f) \times \alpha: f(x) \not \in \alpha, y=0$}.

Clearly, $dom(h) = cf(\aleph_{\alpha})$, $ran(h) \subseteq \alpha$ and $ran(h)$ is cofinal in $(\alpha,\leq)$. It follows that $cf(\alpha) \leq cf(\aleph_{\alpha})$.

How can I prove that the least element $\gamma \in \alpha$ for any $x \in \alpha$?

Thank you!

Comment: Is not the case that $cf(\aleph_\alpha)=cf(\alpha)$ for any $\alpha$ limit? And we can see that because, for any ordinals $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, if $\alpha_1$ is cofinal in $\alpha_2$, then, $cf(\alpha_1)=cf(\alpha_2)$. In fact, $\alpha$ is cofinal in $\aleph_\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\beta= \operatorname{cf}(\aleph_{\alpha})$ and let $f:\beta \to \aleph_{\alpha}$ be strictly increasing and cofinal.

For $\xi \in \beta$, define $g(\xi)=\eta$, where $\vert f(\xi) \vert = \aleph_{\eta}$.  (If $f(\xi) \lt \omega$, define $g(\xi)=0$.)  Then $g:\beta \to \alpha$ is cofinal because $\alpha$ is limit and $f$ is cofinal in $\aleph_{\alpha}$, so $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha) \leq \beta$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the following line of argument why $g$ is cofinal in $(\alpha,\leq)$ correct? Let $x \in \alpha$, then $\aleph_x \in \aleph_{\alpha}$. So, there exists $\theta \in cf(\aleph_{\alpha})$ s.t. $f(\theta) \geq \aleph_x$. But then $\aleph_x \leq |f(\theta)| = \aleph_{\eta}$ for some $\eta \in \alpha$. Hence, $x \leq \eta = g(\theta)$. So it seems we don't even need to assume that $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal for this direction.

Comment: Yes, the argument is correct.